# Gstreamer for Facebook Live

Tags: facebook, gstreamer, live-streaming

I've been fiddling with a gstreamer script to send a rtmp-stream to Facebook Live. I tried a lot of things. The stream works when I send it to my own RTMP-server, but Facebook just won't accept it.

I'm working on a Ubuntu 15.10. I did notice OBS has strange behaviour as well. On a MBP it seems to work, but on my box it won't.

The stream below fits the video/audio-specs mentioned in the Facebook Live. I've listed them here:

> Video Format:
>
> - We accept video in maximum 720p (720 x 1280) resolution, at 30 frames per second. (or 1 key frame every 2 seconds). CHECK
> - You must send an I-frame (keyframe) at least once every two seconds throughout the stream. CHECK
> - Recommended max bit rate is 2500Kbps. CHECK
> - Titles must be less than 255 characters otherwise the stream will fail CHECK
> - The Live API accepts H264 encoded video and AAC encoded audio only CHECK
>
> Video Length:
>
> - 90 minutes maximum length for live stream. CHECK (not specified, so I assume it should be fine)
> - 60 minute maximum length for preview streams (either through Live dialog or publisher tools). After 60 minutes, a new stream key must be
>     generated. CHECK (not specified, so I assume it should be fine)

Advanced Settings:

- Pixel Aspect Ratio: Square CHECK, default behaviour of gstreamer
- Frame Types: Progressive Scan UNCHECKED, progressive scan seems to be the standard to me
- Audio Sample Rate: 44.1 KHz CHECK
- Audio Bitrate: 128 Kbps stereo CHECK
- Bitrate Encoding: CBR CHECK, default behaviour of gstreamer

Gstreamer command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src  ! "video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1" ! x264enc bitrate=2500 key-int-max=10  ! video/x-h264,profile=high ! h264parse ! queue ! flvmux name=mux alsasrc device=hw:1 ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw,rate=44100 ! queue ! voaacenc bitrate=128000 ! queue ! mux. mux. ! rtmpsink location=\"rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?ds=1\&a=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"
```

Did anyone get gstreamer to work for Facebook Live?

Comment: What strange behavior are you observing?  Do you have a link to a public live video where you see the trouble?

Comment: Also, double check our keyframe interval.  Your parameter name might be different, but according to https://sites.google.com/site/linuxencoding/x264-ffmpeg-mapping, it's `keyint`.  And, 10 frames is too small... you will want to set it at 60 for 2-seconds.  Otherwise, you're going to eat all your bandwidth on just those keyframes.

Comment: I gave it a try with a higher key-frame, but no luck. Also the article you linked to is for ffmpeg, I looked the key frame-argument up from the gstreamer-documentation, it should work this way.

Facebook just tells me the video is offline, which is not really helpful.

Comment: Can you post a link to the video, or the ID from the RTMP URL?

Comment: rtmp://146.185.139.238:1935/live/test

Comment: I meant, a link to the video on Facebook, or the part of the RTMP URL that indicates the video ID on Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
video/x-h264,profile=high
```

to:

```
video/x-h264,profile=baseline
```

And it works. I tried with:

```
gst-launch-1.0 flvmux name=mux streamable=true ! rtmpsink location="<rtmp_url_for_fblive>" videotestsrc is-live=true ! "video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1" ! identity sync=true ! x264enc bitrate=2500 key-int-max=60  ! video/x-h264,profile=high ! h264parse ! queue ! mux. audiotestsrc is-live=true ! audio/x-raw,rate=44100,channels=2 ! identity sync=true ! voaacenc bitrate=128000 ! queue ! mux.
```